# Haskell partial function application with $

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, partial-application, parametric-polymorphism

I'm new to Haskell and looking at a simple example of using function application with `$`.

It seems straightforward - it takes a function and applies it to a value.

So this makes sense:

```
> (+3) $ 2
5
```

This also makes sense:

```
> ($) (+3) 2
5
```

This makes sense because the first argument is the function, and the second argument is the value.

Now considering using `$` to create a partial function.

Looking at types, this makes sense - it just needs a `Num` type value for `b`:

```
> :t ($) (+3)
($) (+3) :: Num b => b -> b
```

But here's where I get lost - what is happening here?:

```
> :t ($) (2)
($) (2) :: Num (a -> b) => a -> b
```

I would have expected the first argument would need to be a function, not a simple Num value.

So here's my questions:

1. What's happening here?
2. What does the constraint `Num (a -> b)` syntax mean?
3. What's an example of using `($)` in this way, that starts with something like `($) (2)`?

Thanks!

Comment: Number literals in Haskell don't have fixed types. Try `:t 2` and see. `2`  *can* be a function, if you try hard enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the one hand, numeric literals like `2` are actually read as `fromInteger 2 :: Num a => a` so can denote any value of type `Num a => a`, meaning, any type which is *in* type class `Num`, i.e. has among other things a special version of `fromInteger` defined which returns the actual value of the actual type, converted from the integer `2`:

```
> :i Num
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
```

As [the Haskell Tutorial](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html) puts it (in 10.3),

> An integer numeral (without a decimal point) is actually equivalent to an application of `fromInteger` to the value of the numeral as an `Integer`.

On the other hand, `($)` has the type

```
> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

So we have

```
fromInteger 2 :: Num a1 =>   a1
($)           ::          (a -> b) -> a -> b
--------------------------------------------
($) 2         :: Num      (a -> b) => a -> b
```

So it's a function, which must also be *in* the type class `Num`.

Normally that's not the case but Haskell doesn't know if you could be importing some module which does define such an instance:

```
instance Num (a -> b) where
   ....
   fromInteger n = ....
   ....
```

so it allows this possibility at the type checking, and only then, seeing that there is no such actual instance defined anywhere, it errors out on *that*.

For example, following the hint from [@augustss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649287/augustss) in the comments,

```
instance (Num b) => Num (a -> b) where
   (+) f g x = f x + g x
   (*) f g x = f x * g x
   abs f x = abs (f x)
   negate f x = negate (f x)
   signum f x = signum (f x)
   fromInteger n = const (fromInteger n)
```

lets us write `(sin + 2 * cos^2) x`.

Comment: And making `a->b` an instance of `Num` can actually be quite useful if `b` is also an instance of `Num`.

Comment: could you give a hint as to why and where?

Comment: Try it. :)  You’ll be able to write things like `(sin + 2 * cos) x` instead of `sin x + 2 * cos x`.  It’s not hard to write the instance declaration. The types will force you to the right definition.

Comment: thanks. aha, so `(cos^2) x = (cos x)^2`. I was fixating on `cos^2 = cos . cos` and was stumped by that for a bit...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and example!

Comment: you're welcome. thanks for asking, and staying engaged! :)