# Euler 26 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to solve problem [#26](https://projecteuler.net/problem=26) from Project Euler in Haskell, but I have encountered some problems.

I've managed to figure out that the recurring cycle of the reciprocal is only related to its prime divisors, so I think I just need to find out a reciprocal of a prime number with the longest recurring cycle. So I wrote a algorithm in Haskell:

```hs
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime k
    | k <= 1    = error "Seriously?"
    | otherwise = null [ x | x <- [2..floor(sqrt(fromIntegral k))], k `mod` x == 0]

lp = [x | x <- [7..1000], isPrime x]

s = map (\n -> head [x | x <- [ceiling(logBase 10 (fromIntegral n))..], 10^x `mod` n == 1]) lp

main::IO()
main = print $ maximum s
```

However, it cannot produce an answer. I have tried using the lamda, which could produce the digits of recurring cycle, with a few prime numbers and I manage to get the right count of digits (I hope there would be no problem with the algorithm). I have also checked the output of the list `s`, which produced `[6,2,6,16,18,45,23,15,3,5,63,` without an end. I have no idea why it is the case, since if I manually apply the function to each prime number I can get the right output.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code, or is my way of solving it turns out to be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The algorithm seems ok to me - not particularly efficient, so it may well run for ages, but the values you've printed out seem to be correct (at least those I've checked), and there's no way `s` should be an infinite lift. I'll try testing it myself in ghci if no-one has come up with an explanation by then, but it'll have to wait till I'm at home tonight. [PS for the sake of speed you might just want to find a list of all primes less than 1000 and hard-code that as `lp`.]

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks, I find that the function, if I set the func ```f n =  head [x | x <- [ceiling(logBase 10 (fromIntegral n))..], 10^x `mod` n == 1]``` gives an output if I directly input a prime number like ```f 89```, but it cannot work if replace it with ```f (lp !! 20)```

Comment: @RobinZigmond check out my edit to the answer; not all results were correct, this is how I realized there was some wrap-around arithmetic going on. it wasn't extremely slow, took a few seconds to produce the full list up to 1000.

Comment: @MeowcolmLaw it worked with `89` because it interpeted `89` as a [polymorphic literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54491443/849891) of type `Num a => a`, and defaulted to `Integer`.

Comment: I get frustrated with Haskell typing sometimes. Usually the fix is quick with `fromIntegral` but not here. I got this to work by eliminating the use of `n`  with `[ (n,x) |    i <- [n],   x <- [(ceiling.logBase 10 $ fromIntegral i)..], mod (10^x) i == 1 ]` Use the `i` in place of `n`. You could use `let` but it would be less compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Int` is not  a good choice here, since you operate pretty big numbers, with the `10^x`. `Int` is `Bounded`, so wraps around past its upper bound:

```
> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807

> (maxBound :: Int) + 1
-9223372036854775808
```

Omitting the signature for `isPrime` altogether, we get

```
> :t lp
lp :: Integral b => [b]
```

Trying

```
> map (\n -> (n, head [x | x <- [ceiling(logBase 10 (fromIntegral n))..],
                           10^x `mod` n == 1])) 
      (lp :: [Int])
[(7,6),(11,2),(13,6),(17,16),(19,18),(23,45),(29,23),(31,15),(37,3),(41,5),(43,63),
 (47,Interrupted.
```

we see that your calculation gets stuck on `47`. But using `[Integer]` (or nothing at all, so it defaults to `Integer` by itself), we successfully get the full result. You just misinterpret it. Re-read the problem statement, and you'll see.

<sub>(also, the answer for 43 in the above snippet is incorrect, while those for 7, 11, 13 are correct. Getting wrong results for bigger numbers is a strong signal that we have some integer wrap-around arithmetic errors going on; and that's how I found it out).</sub>